# Get all entries for each topic

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, distinct

I am not sure this is possible with just a query.. (maybe needs some PHP parsing? after the data is returned?)

I have a MySQL table set up.

Columns are as follows:

```
id  
topic   
title   
vimeo_id    
video_length    
speaker_first   
speaker_last    
speaker_designation 
description
```

with records like:

```
1   topic1  title-asda  1719887 speakerFirst-1  speakerLast-1   desc.xxx
2   topic2  title-asdf  1719554 speakerFirst-2  speakerLast-2   desc.xxx
3   topic1  title-ghty  1719445 speakerFirst-3  speakerLast-3   desc.xxx
4   topic3  title-bnh6  1719676 speakerFirst-4  speakerLast-4   desc.xxx
5   topic1  title-gffd  1711121 speakerFirst-5  speakerLast-5   desc.xxx
6   topic4  title-fgdf  1896621 speakerFirst-6  speakerLast-6   desc.xxx
7   topic2  title-tyuu  1005674 speakerFirst-7  speakerLast-7   desc.xxx
```

I am looking to get an output (if possible) like so:

(i.e: unique TOPIC (doesn't need to be listed each time)..  and the sub-records ordered by speaker last)

### Topic1

- title-asda   1719887 speakerFirst-1  speakerLast-1   desc.xxx
- title-ghty   1719445 speakerFirst-3  speakerLast-3   desc.xxx
- title-gffd   1711121 speakerFirst-5  speakerLast-5   desc.xxx

### Topic2

- title-asdf   1719554 speakerFirst-2  speakerLast-2   desc.xxx
- title-tyuu   1005674 speakerFirst-7  speakerLast-7   desc.xxx

### Topic3

- title-bnh6   1719676 speakerFirst-4  speakerLast-4   desc.xxx

### Topic4

- title-fgdf   1896621 speakerFirst-6  speakerLast-6   desc.xxx

If I need to parse this on the php side of things.. (i.e: checking if currentTopic == prevTopic) before outputting it to the screen..  I can do so..  just not sure how to query things to be grouped by topic,...then by speaker_last)

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT topic, speaker_first, speaker_last, title
    FROM vimeo_videos 
    ORDER BY speaker_last DESC
) AS tmp_table GROUP BY topic
```

but it seems to only grab '1' entry for each topic.. not ALL entries under each topic.

this seems to get me the whole list:

```
SELECT * FROM vimeo_videos order by topic, speaker_last;
```

which I guess I could just loop through use PHP and check for a 'new topic to create my 'groupings'?

(just wanted to make sure there isn't a better/more efficient approach)

Comment: You can do this using PHP with just one query (recommended). There is one thing to consider tho: the database architecture. Your topic data column is redundant. I would use the many-to-many relationship and create three tables (topics, speakers and speaker_topic). You could join these tables using `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

What you can do is first do a :

```
SELECT topic FROM mytable GROUP BY topic
```

Then you'll get all the different topics, and for each you can do :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE topic = :mytopic
```

Method 2:

Sort that in php using the usort function with a custom callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..  wouldnt my last query above (more or less) do the same.. with one less query/call?  (since I have to parse with PHP anyways?)

Answer (score -1):

As Nathan said, you can use `GROUP BY` to get just the unique topics, and then make another query that goes through each topic.

Here's an SQL Fiddle example of `GROUP BY`:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/193cd2/1

If you want to reduce the amount of queries, you should do what you said and check for the topic in your `foreach` statement and `ORDER BY topic`